# How to get Android to ask for my choice of phone dialer?

Tags: hardware

I have the default Phoner Dialer on my HTC phone as well as the Doximity Dialer.  When I first installed the Doximity dialer, whenever I made a phone call it would ask which phoner dialer to use the native one or  Doximity and then followed by 'Just once' or 'Always'.  I made the mistake of choosing the native phone dialer and hitting always but cannot for the life of me figure out how do I reset so it goes back to providing me with the choice of a dialer whenever I make a phone call. I have gone under Apps and looked under both the apps properties but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go into *settings  → apps.* Open the menu, and select *show system apps*. Now scroll down to the stock phone app press on it  → *set as default  → clear defaults*. Now, whenever you select a number to call, it will ask which app to use.

If you don't see the *clear defaults* option, then go to *settings  → apps.* Open the menu and press on *reset app preferences* this will clear all your app preferences, including which app should be the default.

Don't worry, this will not delete any data.